# React Native FlatList : Select all Items and run 'OnPress'

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using `react-native-bouncy-checkbox` and `Flatlist`.

> I have created an array object which has `id`, `name`, `amount`.
>
> So far I have achieved:
>
> - User can select individual items from the `Flatlist`, and it will add the `amount` and display it
>   as total amount.
> - User can also edit the `amount` they have selected using TextInput.

---

However, I am trying to create a '*Select All*' feature.

So, when user presses 'Select All' or taps on the 'checkbox' it should:

1. select all the items from the FlatList
2. add the total amount
3. allow user to edit all the selected amount individually
4. update the checkbox to show that it is selected.

---

So far I have tried getting all the 'checkbox' to show that it is selected when 'Select All' text is pressed or when 'checkbox' is pressed (beside select all text).

*I have been trying to get this to work for the last couple of hours but couldn't manage to do it. So any help regarding this issue are most welcome.*

---

**CODE SNIPPETS AND APP SCREENSHOTS PROVIDED BELOW:**

***Code Sample:***

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Divider, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import BouncyCheckbox from 'react-native-bouncy-checkbox';
import TextInputMask from 'react-native-text-input-mask';

function AccountMultiplePayment({ navigation }) {
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'John',
            address: 'address 1',
            amount: '79.90',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Simon',
            address: 'address 2',
            amount: '35.50',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Tim',
            address: 'address 3',
            amount: '15.50',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Rob',
            address: 'address 4',
            amount: '33.33',
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Sarah',
            address: 'address 5',
            amount: '77.77',
        },
    ])

    const [billPaymentAmount, setBillPaymentAmount] = useState({})
    const [selectedBill, setSelectedBill] = useState([]);
    const [totalPaymentAmount, setTotalPaymentAmount] = useState(0);

    const computeBillPaymentAmount = () => {
        let newBillPaymentAmount = {}

        apiData.forEach(({ id, amount }) => {
            newBillPaymentAmount[id] = amount
        })

        return newBillPaymentAmount
    }

    const computeTotalPaymentAmount = () => {
        let total = 0

        selectedBill.forEach(id => {
            total += parseFloat(billPaymentAmount[id])
        })

        // Prevent NaN issue, because once user delete amount will become empty string
        return total ? total : 0
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setBillPaymentAmount(computeBillPaymentAmount())
    }, [apiData])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalPaymentAmount(computeTotalPaymentAmount())
    }, [selectedBill, billPaymentAmount])

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={{ alignItems: 'center', paddingVertical: 10 }}
                    onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}
                >
                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 25 }}>Select All</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <BouncyCheckbox
                        isChecked={checked}
                        fillColor={'green'}
                        unfillColor={'#FFFFFF'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setChecked(!checked)
                        }}
                    />
            </View>
            <FlatList
                data={apiData}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <View style={[styles.subHeaderContainer, { flex: 1 }]}>
                                <Text
                                    style={[
                                        styles.defaultText,
                                        { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 },
                                    ]}>
                                    {item.name}
                                </Text>
                                <Divider style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} />
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                    <Text
                                        style={[styles.defaultText, { fontWeight: 'bold', flex: 2 }]}>
                                        Total Payable Amount:
                                    </Text>
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                        <TextInput
                                            value={billPaymentAmount[item.id]}
                                            onChangeText={value => setBillPaymentAmount({ ...billPaymentAmount, [item.id]: value })}
                                            keyboardType={'numeric'}
                                            mode={'outlined'}
                                            label={'RM'}
                                            dense={true}
                                            render={props =>
                                                <TextInputMask
                                                    {...props}
                                                    mask='[9990].[99]'
                                                />
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <BouncyCheckbox
                                isChecked={checked}
                                fillColor={'green'}
                                unfillColor={'#FFFFFF'}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    if (selectedBill.includes(item.id)) {
                                        setSelectedBill(selectedBill.filter(value => value !== item.id))
                                    } else {
                                        setSelectedBill([...selectedBill, item.id])
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                removeClippedSubviews={false}
            />
            {
                    <>
                        <View
                            style={{
                                paddingVertical: 10,
                                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                backgroundColor:'blue'
                            }}>
                            <Text
                                style={{ color: 'white', flex: 1, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18 }}>
                                Total Amount:{' '}
                            </Text>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 24 }}>
                                    RM {totalPaymentAmount.toFixed(2)}
                                </Text>
                                {totalPaymentAmount <= 0 ? null : (
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            //navigation.goBack();
                                            navigation.goBack();
                                            navigation.navigate('Account');
                                        }}>
                                        <Text>Reset</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )}
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <Button
                            mode={'contained'}
                            color={'limegreen'}
                            style={{
                                borderRadius: 5,
                                marginHorizontal: 20,
                                marginVertical: 10,
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                            }}
                            labelStyle={{ color: 'white', padding: 10 }}
                            uppercase={false}
                            onPress={() => { }}
                            disabled={totalPaymentAmount <= 0 ? true : false}>
                            <Text>Pay Bill</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </>
            }
        </>
    );
}
class Account extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {<AccountMultiplePayment {...this.props} {...this.navigation} />}
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Account;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    headerTitle: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 20,
    },
    subHeaderContainer: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 5,
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
    },
    subHeaderTitle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#2c1855',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    defaultText: {
        color: 'black',
    },
});
```

---

***This is what it looks like currently. All checked items are individually selected:***

[image: current app screenshot]

---

***This is what I am trying to achieve:***

[image: goal for this app]

Comment: You need to create an array that stores checked or not like checkArr = [{checked: false}]. Also, array length must be equalt to your list array. You need to store this array with useState then add & control each element inside list like  checked=checkArr[index]

Comment: I'm wondering how some of the checkboxes can ever be unchecked and some of them are checked. You are using a single state `checked` for all CheckBoxes, thus if this state is true, why aren't all checkboxes selected?

Comment: @DavidScholz for `react-native-bouncy-checkbox` library, when 'OnPress' is pressed, it automatically selects the checkbox and shows green. And pressing again unselects the checkbox.

I used `isChecked` property to see if my `checked` state is working properly or not.
Also `isChecked` property doesn't call the functions like `OnPress`.

Comment: @Orhan if possible, could you provide a runnable example for this. Also here I am using dummy data. In production I will be using data from API. Just wanted to know if that would have any effect on what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: @BeepBoop check new solution implemantion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let refactor code as below

```js
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { Button, Divider, TextInput } from "react-native-paper";
import BouncyCheckbox from "react-native-bouncy-checkbox";

function AccountMultiplePayment({ navigation }) {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John",
      address: "address 1",
      amount: "79.90",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Simon",
      address: "address 2",
      amount: "35.50",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tim",
      address: "address 3",
      amount: "15.50",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Rob",
      address: "address 4",
      amount: "33.33",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Sarah",
      address: "address 5",
      amount: "77.77",
    },
  ]);

  const [billPaymentAmount, setBillPaymentAmount] = useState({});
  const [selectedBill, setSelectedBill] = useState([]);
  const [totalPaymentAmount, setTotalPaymentAmount] = useState(0);

  const computeBillPaymentAmount = () => {
    let newBillPaymentAmount = {};

    apiData.forEach(({ id, amount }) => {
      newBillPaymentAmount[id] = amount;
    });

    return newBillPaymentAmount;
  };

  const computeTotalPaymentAmount = () => {
    let total = 0;

    selectedBill.forEach((id) => {
      total += parseFloat(billPaymentAmount[id]);
    });

    // Prevent NaN issue, because once user delete amount will become empty string
    return total ? total : 0;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setBillPaymentAmount(computeBillPaymentAmount());
  }, [selectedBill.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotalPaymentAmount(computeTotalPaymentAmount());
  }, [billPaymentAmount]);

  const selectAllBill = () => {
    if (selectedBill.length < apiData.length) {
      setSelectedBill([...new Set(apiData.map((item) => item.id))]);
    }

    if (selectedBill.length === apiData.length) {
      setSelectedBill([]);
    }
  };

  const isBillAdded = (id) => selectedBill.some((el) => el === id);

  const hasAllBillselected = apiData.length === selectedBill.length;

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ alignItems: "center", paddingVertical: 10 }}
          onPress={selectAllBill}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 25 }}>Select All</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <BouncyCheckbox
          disableBuiltInState
          isChecked={hasAllBillselected}
          fillColor={"green"}
          unfillColor={"#FFFFFF"}
          onPress={selectAllBill}
        />
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={apiData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <View style={[styles.subHeaderContainer, { flex: 1 }]}>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.defaultText,
                    { fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 16 },
                  ]}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
                <Divider style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.defaultText,
                      { fontWeight: "bold", flex: 2 },
                    ]}
                  >
                    Total Payable Amount:
                  </Text>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <TextInput
                      value={billPaymentAmount[item.id]}
                      onChangeText={(value) =>
                        setBillPaymentAmount({
                          ...billPaymentAmount,
                          [item.id]: value,
                        })
                      }
                      keyboardType={"numeric"}
                      mode={"outlined"}
                      label={"RM"}
                      dense={true}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <BouncyCheckbox
                disableBuiltInState
                isChecked={selectedBill.includes(item.id)}
                fillColor={"green"}
                unfillColor={"#FFFFFF"}
                onPress={() => {
                  if (selectedBill.includes(item.id)) {
                    setSelectedBill(
                      selectedBill.filter((value) => value !== item.id)
                    );
                  } else {
                    setSelectedBill([...new Set([...selectedBill, item.id])]);
                  }
                }}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
      />
      {
        <>
          <View
            style={{
              paddingVertical: 10,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              flexDirection: "row",
              backgroundColor: "blue",
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                color: "white",
                flex: 1,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                fontSize: 18,
              }}
            >
              Total Amount:{" "}
            </Text>
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 24 }}
              >
                RM {totalPaymentAmount.toFixed(2)}
              </Text>
              {totalPaymentAmount <= 0 ? null : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    //navigation.goBack();
                    navigation.goBack();
                    navigation.navigate("Account");
                  }}
                >
                  <Text>Reset</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>

          <Button
            mode={"contained"}
            color={"limegreen"}
            style={{
              borderRadius: 5,
              marginHorizontal: 20,
              marginVertical: 10,
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            labelStyle={{ color: "white", padding: 10 }}
            uppercase={false}
            onPress={() => {}}
            disabled={totalPaymentAmount <= 0 ? true : false}
          >
            <Text>Pay Bill</Text>
          </Button>
        </>
      }
    </>
  );
}
class Account extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = false;
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>{<AccountMultiplePayment {...this.props} {...this.navigation} />}</>
    );
  }
}

export default Account;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    alignItems: "center",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  subHeaderContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 5,
    marginVertical: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  subHeaderTitle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#2c1855",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  defaultText: {
    color: "black",
  },
});
```

Working example here - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/971a0c

Comment: Glad to hear that !

Answer (score 3):

After checking the [documentation of react-native-bouncy-checkbox](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-bouncy-checkbox), the following is important.

1. `isChecked`determines the default internal checkbox state. It is only evaluated once.
2. The `check`-state handling is handled internally by the library.
3. We want to handle this on our own, in order to check all checkbox with a single state change. To do so, we need to set the `disableBuiltInState` prop to true "if you want to manually handle the isChecked prop and disable built in handling".

Thus, I would suggest the following workflow.

1. Create a state array for `isChecked` which contains a boolean flag for each of the elements.
2. Create a custom `onPress`-handler which gets the index from the `FlatList` as a parameter. With that index, we are able to to set the correct boolean flag in our state array to `true` or `false`.
3. If `Select All` is pressed, our `onPress`-handler sets all boolean flags of our state array to `true`. This will cause a rerendering of our screen and since we set `disableBuiltInState` prop to `true`, react-native-bouncy-checkbox will use our custom state handling.

Here is a minimal working example.

```js
// set inititial all to false, you might want some different initial state
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState(Array.from({ length: apiData.length }, () => false))

  const onCheck = React.useCallback(
    (index) => {
      let previous = [...checks]
      previous[index] = !previous[index]
      setChecks(previous)
    },
    [checks, setChecks]
  )

  const selectAll = React.useCallback(() => {
    let previous = [...checks]
    setChecks(previous.map(() => true))
  }, [checks, setChecks])

return (
    <View style={{ padding: 40, marginTop: 50 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={apiData}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
            <BouncyCheckbox
              isChecked={checks[index]}
              fillColor={"green"}
              unfillColor={"#FFFFFF"}
              onPress={() => onCheck(index)}
              disableBuiltInState={true}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => "" + item.id}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={selectAll}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "red" }}> Select All</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

This looks as follows.

[image]

Pressing `Select All` yields

[image]

Since you want to calculate additional values (total payable amount for each selected item) I would suggest to just add the `checks` state to your already implemented `useEffect`. When the `checks` state changes, this `useEffect` will be called. You can calculate all fields for which the boolean flag inside `checks` is true and set the state for the input fields.

Comment: I was thinking of making an answer but this one is better than what I would've answered. I also think `totalPaymentAmount` doesn't need to be a state variable. If its not set as a `const` I think its value can just be updated in an `useEffect` tied to the checks

Comment: @PhantomSpooks Thanks! And I agree, totalPaymentAmount doesn't need to be a state variable. It should be recalculated on each rerender anyway.

Comment: @DavidScholz Thank you for your solution and clear explanation.

Comment: You are very welcome!